# Realtek Alc662 can't enable 5.1 surround

Tags: sound, alsa, realtek

I have a Lenovo thinkcentre M90 with onboard audio Realtek Alc662 and surround Creative inspire T6100. I have only 2 ch sound. I have sound only from front speakers and subwoofer.

```
0 - Front Left
1 - Front Right
2 - Unused
3 - Unused
4 - Unused
5 - Unused
```

My Pulseaudio daemon.conf has `enable-lfe-remixing = yes`

```
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Pulseaudio manager

```
Default sample type : s16le 6ch 44100Hz
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Sample type: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel map: front-left,front-right
```

`/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` has `Run=No`

I've tried adding
`options snd-hda-intel model=3stack-6ch` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, but no result

I've tried adding
`options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=3stack-6ch` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`; nothing again.

I've tried editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device_id=0 channels=5 channel_map=.......
```

Nothing again.

I've tried editing `/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.sndcard{
type hw
card 0
device 1
channels 6
}
```

NOTHING

```
pcm.!default {
type plug
slave.pcm “surround51″
slave.channels 6
route_policy duplicate
}
```

NOTHING
AND bunch of other configs - STILL THE SAME

`aplay-l`

```
**** Списък на PLAYBACK хардуерни устройства ****
карта 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], устройство 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство #0: subdevice #0
карта 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство #0: subdevice #0
карта 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство #0: subdevice #0
карта 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство #0: subdevice #0
карта 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -v`

```
0

0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Core Processor DMI
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fa000000-fb0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel

00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel

00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 00aa:0059
    Flags: fast devsel

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at fb149000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at f100 [size=8]
    Memory at fb148000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at fb120000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fb147000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fb146000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at fb140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fb145000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Q57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f0f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0e0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at fb144000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f050 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Bitland(ShenZhen) Information Technology Co., Ltd. GT218 [GeForce 310]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Bitland(ShenZhen) Information Technology Co., Ltd. High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fb080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: i7core_edac
    Kernel modules: i7core_edac

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

This is my Alsamixer

[image]

Any suggestions to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We're going to begin by asking the obvious questions:

1. Have you tried playing back any surround sound sources?
2. Your first step should be from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio

I was able to use that method to get surround sound working out of SPDIF on a similar audio chipset.

Comment: This should be a comment - please don't write an answer to ask for clarification from OP!

Comment: I`ve just tried the link you gave me . Still same 2 ch sound - rear left - rear right and lfe . Sitll don`t have surround 5.1 in pulse audio control settings. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I really need other suggestion ! Help please